# "Cleanskin" meaning untattooed in Australian English

Tags: meaning, word-usage

According to [Macquarie Dictionary](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/) one recent definition of ***cleanskin*** is ***untattooed***.

Is this just a regionalism  or is this usage found also in British and American English?

(None of the common online dictionaries such as ; M-W, Oxford, Cambridge etc. show the above definition)

Comment: *behind* a paywall ;) So where did you first see this term? If you supply the source it's an upvote from me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the AusEng slang meaning, ***untattooed***,  is derived from "unbranded", an animal whose skin is NOT permanently marked with a symbol by means of a *branding iron*

[image: branding iron]

> **[cleanskin](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cleanskin)**
>   noun mainly Australian
>   1. an unbranded animal
>   2. *slang*
>     a person without a criminal record
>   3. a terrorist who has no obvious links to terrorist groups, 
>   and who thus does not appear on police watch lists
>   4. *Australian and New Zealand*
>     a bottle of wine whose label does not display the producer's name

Collins Dictionary

Comment: Yes, the derivation from unbranded cattle seems logical, but is this connotation known outside Australia?

Comment: Never heard it used in the UK, nor read it anywhere online.

Comment: Third-Generation Tattooist Stands Out for Having 'Clean Skin' - https://www.tattoodo.com/a/2016/11/third-generation-tattooist-stands-out-for-having-clean-skin/

Comment: If you are a Clean skin (Have no tattoos) .....https://m.facebook.com/Allureinktattoostudio/posts/305607506755010/

Comment: @user067531 those links with a summary would go better in your question.